# Drivers disable lights

Tags: lighting, drivers

I wanted to use drivers to finely control the output of my scene lamps. But attaching a driver to the "Power" field causes the lamp to not render at all, even though the number I want is still appearing in the field. This is happening in both eevee and cycles.

The driver is controlled by the Z-location of another object, which is animated using the "follow path" constraint. The expression gives me the value I'm expecting, but that value doesn't seem to be actually used by the lamp as long as the driver is active.

[Here is an example of the problem.](https://pasteall.org/blend/ecbf60f3a4414394b320717e5687bbc9)

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps you could [edit] in an example file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The power is set to mW, you want to at least multiply the driver expression by 10 or 100 to see the effect. Or scale your path up in object world

Comment: So basically I had to increase the number. Kind of sad that I didn't think of that, but I didn't notice the unit change.